# api-easy - vows - setting cookie issue

Tags: node.js, angularjs, unit-testing

I am using `api-easy` with `vows` for `API testing`. one of my api require a authenticated login to access the list of data.

So 1st i did the login with `/api/session` & extacted the cookie & used it in my 2nd api call. But it still gives me error - `unauthorised`.

```
var cookies;

suite.discuss('When using your awesome API')
.use('localhost', 9000)
.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
.post('/api/session', {'username': 'siteadmin', 'password': 'siteadmin' })
.expect(200)
    .expect('should login', function (err, res, body) {
        res.headers['set-cookie'].filter(function (cookie) {
            if (!!~cookie.indexOf('connect.sid')) {
                cookies = cookie.split(';', 1)[0];
            }
        })    
    })
.next()
.discuss('and your awesome resource')
.use('localhost', 9000)
.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
.setHeader('Cookie', cookies)
.get('/api/list/name')
.expect(200)
.export(module);
```

Have any idea how to get this running?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
suite.discuss('When using your awesome API')
.use('localhost', 9000)
.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
.post('/api/session', {'username': 'siteadmin', 'password': 'siteadmin' })
.expect(200)
    .expect('should login', function (err, res, body) {
        assert.include(res.headers, 'set-cookie');
        suite.before('setAuth', function (outgoing) {
                outgoing.headers['Cookie'] = res.headers['set-cookie'][0];
                return outgoing;
        });  
    })
.next()
.discuss('and your awesome resource')
.use('localhost', 9000)
.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
.get('/api/list/name')
.expect(200)
.export(module);
```

I removed the cookies variable and used the suite.before method to inject the cookie in the headers.

From the moment you have defined the suite.before function, the cookie will be set in all sequential requests in the suite. Thus, you can split the above example in two tests:

```
suite.discuss('When using your awesome API')
.use('localhost', 9000)
.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

suite.discuss('and sending login data to')
.post('/api/session', {'username': 'siteadmin', 'password': 'siteadmin' })
.expect(200)
    .expect('should login', function (err, res, body) {
        assert.include(res.headers, 'set-cookie');
        suite.before('setAuth', function (outgoing) {
                outgoing.headers['Cookie'] = res.headers['set-cookie'][0];
                return outgoing;
        });  
    });

suite.discuss('then after login')
.get('/api/list/name')
.expect(200);

suite.export(module);
```